# Javascript: When and when not to use "this"

Tags: javascript, function, scope, this

Im curious when it is needed/best practice to use the keyword `this`. I understand that `this` is used when determining a functions `this` value but is it always needed?

The reason I am asking is because I have a internal function and it is called within my module and all it really does is sort some data you pass it. My question is should I call this function using the `this` keyword or stand alone.

E.g:

```
function formatSomeData(data){
  //code........
}

this.formatSomeData(data);

        OR

formatSomeData(data);
```

I get that the context of where the function is being called and what its purpose is matters in answering the question, but in this case like I mentioned, I really don't need to access the `this` object at any point. Is it still good practice to use it when calling functions? 
What I'm asking is not so much as to how "this" works, but when is it appropriate to use it and when isn't it.

Comment: If its a `method` of some kind, that means that the function is somehow directly related to an object, then its a good design decision to use `this`. Otherwise not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: By the way `this.formatSomeData(data);` wont work in your case so the answer is obvious

Comment: @JonasW. it might. In non-strict mode, `this` will point to `window` and any declaration not in a function will be a part of global scope.

Comment: @rajesh "in non-strict mode" ... talking about bad practices here...

Comment: use 'this' keyword, when you are referring to the same object or want to call a method on the current object. If you have standalone method in an object, if you are invoking it from the same object, you can call using 'this' or even directly. 'this' is mainly used for readability i.e. we are invoking a method from the same object

Comment: @JonasW. practices comes in play when you have some knowledge about language. For a beginner, its difficult for to decide if they are on right/wrong path. Especially with JS where you can do same thing in 10 different ways. So even if its bad, its possible and many will use it

Comment: @JonasW. Have credited you in answer and have tried to give some explanation as to why it is a bad approach. If there are more, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when it is needed/best practice to use the keyword this

This is usually used when you want to access something in some. So for instance, if you have a custom object and want to use some property inside some method, you should use `this`.

```js
function Person(fname, lname){
  this.fname = fname;
  this.lname = lname;
  this.fullName = function(){
    return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
  }
}

var p = new Person('foo', 'bar');
console.log(p.fullName())
```

If you see, in current constructor, I created a function(`fullName`) which needs to access `fname` and `lname` properties of the object it is part of. This is a place `this` must be used.

---

> Now while declaration, when to use `this`?

Any property in a constructor that is a part of `this` will be a part of the object. So if you need something that is only accessible to you but not outside, you can use `function` instead of `this`.

```js
function Person(fname, lname){
  var self = this;
  self.fname = fname;
  self.lname = lname;
  
  // This function is private
  function getFullName() {
    var name = '';
    var seperator = '';
    if (fname) {
      name += self.fname;
      seperator = ' ';
    }
    if (lname) {
      name += seperator + self.lname;
    }
    return name;
  }
  this.fullName = function(){
    return getFullName();
  }
}

var p = new Person('foo', 'bar');
console.log(p.fullName())
```

---

As for your code, I have already explained in comment why it works:

> In non-strict mode, `this` will point to `window` and any declaration not in a function will be a part of global scope.

But as rightly pointer by @[Jonas W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-w) its a bad practice. Why it is bad?

- Any variable defined without declaration statement(`var|let|const`) will become part of global scope.
- Any variable with declaration statement outside any functions will become part of global scope.

Comment: This definetly outlines the technical point of this. Good job :) (and very nice to mention me)

Comment: JonasW, Thanks. @PhilDimeski Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

For a starting JS developer it might be easiest to get concept of This by using it in an event listener callback. I. e., "click" event binds This to object which is the target (Like "look, i clicked on THIS!").

```
<ul class="dynamic-list" id="myList">
  <li class="dynamic-list__item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="dynamic-list__item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="dynamic-list__item">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  let listItems = document.getElementById("myList").childNodes;
  [...listItems].forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener("click", removeListItem, false);
  })

  // Callback for event, using THIS
  function removeListItem() {
    // Log the text content of <li> to the console. Which one? THIS one.
    console.log(this.textContent);

    // Get the parent of what? Of THIS! And remove its child. Which one? THIS one!          
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
  }

</script>
```

Of course Rajeshs answer is much, much more complex, but I hope THIS can be also helpful…

Answer (score 0):

Programming is a way to express things so that computers *and* humans can understand them.

> Is it still good practice to use it when calling functions?

There is no exact answer. Both of your snippets do work. So the computer is able to understand it. However the second one is maybe confusing for humans (aka your coworkers):

```
 this.someFunc();
```

What should `this` refer to? Yes technically it refers to `window`, but from a human point of view it is unclear.
Thats why i would definetly not refer to `this` in this case. However there are other good usecases for it:

```
 function changeColor(){
   //When just looking here it makes no sense to refer to this
   this.color = "green";
}

const car = { color: "grey" };

 //But now it makes sense as `this` refers to the `car` it is called on
car.changeColor = changeColor;
```

TLDR: Use `this` to refer to methods/properties, and leave it away when refering to pure functions and variables.

Answer (score 0):

Let me help  you with this piece of code!

```
let emp_detail={
 fname:"jemish",
 lname:"italiya",
 detailStatement:function() {
  return this.fname+" "+this.lname;
  }
}
```

Let me give you another example

```
function Data(){
return this.result
}
var a=Data.bind({result:"I am the result!"})();
console.log(a)    //I am the result!
```

Answer (score -1):

'This' is used inside a function and it contains the value of the object that invokes the function.

For example:

```
function a(){
 this.newVariable = 'Phil';
}
a();
console.log(newVariable); //This line would display Phil
```

In this case, even though we just define newVariable inside the function a(). The object that invokes the function is the global object window, so 'this' points to window and this.newVariable is at the global scope.

Another example would be:

```
var c={
  log:function(){
    this.name = 'Phil';
   }    
}
```

In this case, 'this' points to the object c, since the log function will be invoked by c.

We have more tricky cases in the use of the object 'this' in Javascript. This is a good article to grasp the concept: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Answer (score -1):

One could see this as an argument that has a default value. Consider the
`apply` and `call` functions.

```js
function theThis () {
  return this
}

theThis.call('hello') // => "hello"
theThis.apply('world') // => "world"
```

This example is not an explanation of the behavior of `this`, but more
a demonstration of the use of `this` as an argument that isn't part of the
arguments array. You could say it is an argument that has its own special
keyword.

The exact value that `this` becomes; depends on a (long) list of rules. The
`this` keyword can therefore be confusing and often unnecessarily so. In most
cases, it is better to write your code in a way that makes the use of `this`
redundant. Let's look at a `fullName` example.

```js
function fullName({firstName, lastName}) {
  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`
}

const person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
}

fullName(person) // => "John Doe"
```

We implemented the complete `fullName` feature without `this`, which is great
because we don't have to worry about the rules of `this`. Therefore, we don't
need to use `call`, `bind`, and `apply` to force the function to be called with
the correct `this`. Not to mention, the `() => {}` syntax for defining
functions which adds to the list of how the value of `this` is determined.

Some people might want an object that also contains methods that can be
instantiated, the prototypal inheritance approach. This common approach is not
OK as it will cause confusion in many cases. Assigning a function on the object
to another object is one of those examples. Just because you know this little
trick, does not mean a developer with a different programming background knows
about this (confusing) behavior.

```
> a = {id: 0, thiz() { return this; } }
{ id: 0, thiz: [Function: thiz] }
> b = {id: 1}
{ id: 1 }
> b.thiz = a.thiz
[Function: thiz]
> b.thiz()
{ id: 1, thiz: [Function: thiz] }
```

By doing this you have also conflated computed properties and behaviours with
the state.

> I remember running into these bugs where I would assign a method to the view
> model of some SPA component. Poor me back in the early days of Angular.

I often read that the use of `this` enables code re-use and concise
implementations. I find this statement to be untrue and misleading. Let's
compare implementations of the `fullName` example.

### With `this`

```js
class Person {
  constructor(details)  {
    Object.assign(this, details)
  },
  fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
  }
}

export default Person

//

import Person from './person.mjs'

new Person({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
}).fullName()
```

### Without `this`

```js
export function fullName({firstName, lastName}) {
  return `${firstName} ${lastName}`
}

//

import { fullName } from './person.mjs'

fullName({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
})
```

The implementation without `this`

- has fewer objects
- is written with less code
- requires less knowledge of the language
- is just as expressive.

However, there are use-cases for using `this` that are very specific.

### Keeping backwards compatibility while passing more state to a function.

Previously, I showed that you can write functions without `this`. But what if
code ends up being used, and you want to re-use that code while extending
functionality? Here you need an "escape-hatch." The `this` can be exactly that.
You are most likely still better off doing a major version bump and updating
the consuming code to adopt those changes. If, however, you need or want to
keep the API, the `this` can be your way out to pass some extra state.

### The library I'm using already uses `this`.

Don't be too strict about not using `this` and adopt the API of the library you
end up picking. The designer of that library should assume their API is being
used the way they prescribe it. If you don't like it, consider using
a different library or write your own.

**Conclusion:** Using `this` incorrectly can lead to confusion in JavaScript code. It is
recommended to become familiar with module and lexical scoping to write more
readable code. Avoiding the dynamic behavior of `this` can also help in this
regard. Additionally, most features of JavaScript, such as prototypal
inheritance, can be used without relying on the `this` keyword.

**Links:**

- https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/removing-javascripts-this-keyword-makes-it-a-better-language-here-s-why-db28060cc086/

Comment: I might be a bit to harsh when it comes to my statement of not using prototypal inheritance. Nothing wrong with the prototype chain. The nice thing is that you can still use prototype chain without the use of this.